org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1195725856 larger than 104857600)
Steps I have followed-

Installed docker
Installed Zookeeper
using cmd docker run -d --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 zookeeper:3.5
Started Kafka
using cmd docker run -d --name kafka -p 9092:9092 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=<ip_addr>:2181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://<ip_addr>:9092 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 confluentinc/cp-kafka

getting this error
enter image description here
I'm using **kafkajs **on my server to connect and produce messages.
I want to run kafka locally and publish to a topic which will be subcribed on another server

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
